# PyQT: about button in menu bar

Tags: python, pyqt

How to add an 'about' button to the menu bar of your main window - which when clicked directly opens a dialog with some about text - using  PyQT?

Or is that impossible?

Having had a look at the documentation/question and answers online having to do with the menu bar, I get the impression that the QMenuBar only supports triggering events via 'QAction's via menu drop-downs. However I dont want a drop-down for the about button but rather would like it to trigger some showAboutDialog method.

If you have any ideas/links please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `QAction` object directly to the menubar of your MainWindow. Use the `QMenuBar.addAction()` method for this:

```
class YourMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        menu = QMenuBar()
        menu.addAction(show_about_dialog_action)
        self.setMenuBar(menu)
```